# How do I check if x is in a variable in classes within a list?

Tags: swift

I have a list called mainframe which holds classes. I want to check before adding a new username; if newusername is in mainframe.usernames perform adding the new username in.

pretty much something like this:

```
import UIKit

class addNewPassword: UIViewController {

    var homeVC = Home()

    @IBOutlet weak var createHolderItem: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var createHolderUsername: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var createHolderPassword: UITextField!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }
    @IBAction func savePasswordButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let holder = Holder()
        holder.item = createHolderItem.text!
        holder.username = createHolderUsername.text!
        holder.password = createHolderPassword.text!
    }

  if mainframe.contains(where: { $0.username == holder.username }) {
        print("test")
    }
    else {
            homeVC.mainframe.append(holder)
            homeVC.tableView.reloadData()

            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

}
```

I pretty much want to run a loop, within an if statement. Or am I approaching it the wrong way?

I'm new to programming, did online tutorials and trying to write my first iOS app for my aunt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if mainframe.usernames.contains(holder.username) {
...
```

Comment: Sends back an error "expected declaration". And sorry, I think i didn't ask the question properly. I have a variable called mainframe : [Holder] = [class0, class1, class2] .  And those classes are what's in the code above. How do I access a class within a variable? i tried mainframe.Holder.username, but no resolution

Comment: You can access the member of those classes by accessing their position in the array, something like `mainframe[0].username`. If you want to know if any of the classes in the array has the username you want, try this: `if mainframe.contains(where: { $0.username == holder.username }) { ...`.

Comment: yeah, i'm looking for the latter, thanks a lot!
I keep getting error "expected declaration" when I put "if mainframe.contains(where: { $0.username == holder.username })" what does that mean?

Comment: That means "checking if the array contains any objects whose username equals holder.username". That should work since you have an array of `Holder` where each has an `username` property.

Comment: I meant what does the error "expected declaration" mean

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's hard to tell, I would actually need more context of where your is inserted, but that's usually for misplaced code. For instance, when you're trying to place that code in the scope of a class or there are missing brackets or something.

Comment: Your `if` and `else` should be inside `savePasswordButton(_:)` function. Note that the code is outside the function, being in at class scope.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`contains`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains) :

```
if mainframe.usernames.contains(holder.username) {
    ...
}
```